# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str in knn

Tags: python, pandas

I want to code image classification, using `hough transform` for feature extraction, and classification using `kNN`, can someone help me to solve the error:

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str in knn.

This is the code:

```
def KNN():
    txt=[]
    test=[]
    pathknn = "f:\Data\Classifiers\KNN"
    if not os.path.exists(pathknn):
        os.makedirs(pathknn)

    data = pd.read_csv('F:\Data\hough\\'+txt+'.txt' + str)
    data=shuffle(data, random_state=0)
```

Comment: `txt` is a list, you're never adding anything to that list, and you're trying to add it to a string in the file path of the `csv`. it is unclear what you're trying to do here

Comment: What is this function supposed to do? It looks like you are trying to build the path of a csv file (but named with .txt). Are you sure you are using the correct variable there? Perhaps you mean to use another one that holds the name of the file? Or you may have meant to use the list to store file names and you want to open a few csv files?

Answer (score 1):

You can't construct string and list-objects. You may need to run a loop for that like this.

```
txts = ["one", "two"]
["location/"+(txt +".txt) for txt in txts]
```

Output: ["location/one.txt", "location/two.txt"]